# Classification of n-dimensional rook subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

The $n$-dimensional rook graph is the Cartesian product $K_\infty^n$. Letting $\mathcal{G}_n$ be the family of (finite connected) induced subgraphs, my question is how to classify $\mathcal{G}_n$, or at at least non-trivial families $\mathcal{F}_n \supseteq \mathcal{G}_n \supseteq \mathcal{H}_n$.

It is known that $\mathcal{G}_2$ is the family of line graphs of bipartite graphs, however for larger $n$, I am unsure how it extends. Currently, the best I have is letting $\mathcal{F}_n$ be the family of connected graphs that do not have a star with $n+2$ nodes as an induced subgraph, and letting $\mathcal{H}_n$ be the union of all Cartesian products of $K_i \times \mathcal{H}_{n-1}$ for all finite $i$.

Edit: I’m also particularly interested in “constructable”/“nice” families. While I may be able to say $\mathcal{G}_n$ is the family of graphs $G$ where the intersection graph of the maximal cliques of $G$ has an $n$-coloring, and every edge belongs to only one maximal clique, I find that definition very opaque and hard to work with. (I’m not sure $n$-colorability necessarily implies $G \in \mathcal{G}_n$, but my point still stands)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't every finite graph a subgraph of $K_\infty$, and hence of $K_\infty^n$? Do you perhaps mean to only consider induced subgraphs?

Comment: yes, my mistake, fixed